# Update registro BD desde un modal con javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, modal

Buenas estoy haciendo modificaciones de la Bd desde modales. Lo tengo todo realizado pero me devuelve error de que no se a podido hacer el update, alguna sugerencia???

Los datos al modal los envio asi:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
                var id=$(this).val();
                var IdUsuario=$('#IdUsuario'+id).text();
                var Name=$('#Name'+id).text();
                var Nif=$('#Nif'+id).text();
                var Direccion=$('#Direccion'+id).text();
                var Poblacion=$('#Poblacion'+id).text();
                var Postal=$('#Postal'+id).text();
                var Provincia=$('#Provincia'+id).text();
                var Email=$('#Email'+id).text();
                var Telefono=$('#Telefono'+id).text();
                var Movil=$('#Movil'+id).text();
                var Web=$('#Web'+id).text();
                var Informacion=$('#Informacion'+id).text();
                var Estado=$('#Estado'+id).children('span').first().text();

                $('#edit').modal('show');
                $('#eIdUsuario').val(IdUsuario);
                $('#eName').val(Name);
                $('#eNif').val(Nif);
                $('#eDireccion').val(Direccion);
                $('#ePoblacion').val(Poblacion);
                $('#ePostal').val(Postal);
                $('#eProvincia').val(Provincia);
                $('#eEmail').val(Email);
                $('#eTelefono').val(Telefono);
                $('#eMovil').val(Movil);
                $('#eWeb').val(Web);
                $('#eInformacion').val(Informacion);
                $('#eEstado').val(Estado);

            });
        });
    </script>
```

En el modal los recibo asi:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont corpiii" id="eName" name="eName">
```

Con este script los mando para hacer el update:

```
<script>
      $(function(){
          $("#formuploadajax").on("submit", function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var f = $(this);
              var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formuploadajax"));
              formData.append("dato", "valor");
              //formData.append(f.attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
              $.ajax({
                  url: "act-clientes.php",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "html",
                  data: formData,
                  cache: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false
              })
                  .done(function(res){
                      $("#mensaje").html(res);
                      toastr["success"]("Módulo Editado", "Mensaje")
                      //setTimeout(function () {
                            // window.location.href = "hifu.php"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
                         //}, 1500); //will call the function after 2 secs
                  });
          });
      });
    </script>
```

Y asi intento hacer el update:

```
<?php
  $id = $_POST['eIdUsuario'];
  $name = $_POST['eName'];
  //$estado = ['estado'];
  $nif = $_POST['eNif'];
  $direccion = $_POST['eDireccion'];
  $poblacion = $_POST['ePoblacion'];
  $postal = $_POST['ePostal'];
  $provincia = $_POST['eProvincia'];
  $email = $_POST['eEmail'];
  $telefono = $_POST['eTelefono'];
  $movil = $_POST['eMovil'];
  $web = $_POST['eWeb'];
  $informacion = $_POST['eInformacion'];
  //$banco = ['eBanco'];
  //$swift = ['eSwift'];

  $results = 'Update Usuarios Set Nombre="$name", Dni="$nif", Direccion="$direccion", Poblacion="$poblacion", Postal="$postal", Provincia="$provincia", Username="$email", Telefono="$telefono", Movil="$movil", Web="$web", Informacion="$informacion" where IdUsuario= $id';

  if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $results)) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
  } else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
  }
  mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```